# C++: Initializer list + template yields strange error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, initializer-list

Consider the following code:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct X{
    static void init(const std::initializer_list<void*>& ptrs){}
};

template <typename T>
struct Y{   

    static void foo(){
        X::init({ nullptr });
    }

};
```

The function `foo` of class template `Y<T>` calls `X::init` with an initializer list with a single `nullptr`. Should work fine, shouldn't it?

However, my g++ 4.6.1 complains:

```
test11.cpp: In static member function 'static void Y<T>::foo()':
test11.cpp:12:23: error: no matching function for call to 'X::init(<brace-enclosed initializer list>&)'
test11.cpp:12:23: note: candidate is:
test11.cpp:5:15: note: static void X::init(const std::initializer_list<void*>&)
test11.cpp:5:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const std::initializer_list<void*>&'
```

Once I remove the template parameter from `Y`, i.e. make it a normal class, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Seems to [work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/bfab5d5ff6a33911b50b4bf1f8f1fd4d) on GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: But seems to [not work](http://ideone.com/MzzS9) on GCC 4.5.1.

Comment: I'm guessing it was a bug if it works like that with a later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost definitely a compiler bug, seeing that it works in later versions of GCC (see comments). I personally don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: but then it is a quite strange one. The template parameter is never used. I can't see why templating `Y` should make any difference on the initializer list call. Is there a bugfix log for gcc?

Comment: @gexicide, That's how C++ and C++ compilers work. Just to confuse you.

Comment: @gexicide, I use this: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html. It works wonderfully and includes other useful things like boost.

Comment: @chris: What is the best way to migrate to this distro? Uninstall old one first or can I simply install it over the old one?

Comment: @gexicide, Which compiler do you use? It comes with instructions, but with CodeBlocks, all I have to do is replace `MinGW` with this renamed to that.